# I don't understand what it saying?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

Warning: Undefined array key "pro_widgets" in E:\xammp\htdocs\vc\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\api.php on line 160

Comment: Well this seems like a warning beacuse of elementor plugin. To get rid of it initially you can turn your debug off. https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
Also, what PHP version are you at ? And have you downloaded it from the legit sources ?

Comment: I'd guess its  using a pro module for an install of Elementor that isn't registered as pro

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70964887/612253 for a temporary fix.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that on line 160 of the file at that path, there is a statement which is looking for a key called "pro_widgets" in some array, but that key has not been defined, so it can't get the value.

Comment: This is correct, but as this is a plugin(elementor), the author should not edit it any core files of it, in my opinion.

Comment: i just commented this line it works