# Elementor error when Editing the Page Warning: Undefined array key "pro_widgets" in *\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\api.php on line 160

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

When I try to edit the page with elementor I get this error and the pro widgets isn't showing (I have the free elementor but planning on getting the pro)

I updated the elementor plugin and theme and tried to uninstall some plugins but its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please try to switch them and check.

There may be a file conflict issue.
Make sure your WP setup and plugin are with the latest version

Comment: I disabled all my plug-ins and updated everything and its still not working

Comment: Please share screenshots or URLs so I can check in detail.

Comment: Am building the website on local host do you want a screen shot of a specific thing?

Answer (score 0):

What you need in **api.php line 160** is to check whether a variable is set and is not NULL using **isset**.

Inside the **get_promotion_widget()** function
change it to like this:

```
public static function get_promotion_widgets() {
    $data = self::get_info_data();

    if ( ! isset( $data['pro_widgets'] ) ) {
        $data['pro_widgets'] = [];
    }

    return $data['pro_widgets'];
}
```

And the warning should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it temporarily by adding one line to the function, as below. Unfortunately this kind of temporary fix needs to be reapplied each time the Elementor plugin is updated, so it's not a good long term solution.

```
public static function get_promotion_widgets() {
    $data = self::get_info_data();

    if ( ! isset( $data['pro_widgets'] ) ) {
        if (!is_array($data)) $data = []; # Added
        $data['pro_widgets'] = [];
    }

    return $data['pro_widgets'];
}
```

The function can be found in wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/api.php at around line 160.

I've submitted my fix to the plugin developers through github, so hopefully it will make it into the plugin code.